# grid package: Save plot of multiple grobs in one object

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-grid

I'm assembling several grobs in one image. I can save the output to file in RStudio, but how can I assign it to an object inside R?

Here is an example:

> ```
> library(ggplot2)
> library(grid)
>
> #create the plot
> plot <- ggplot(mtcars) +
>           geom_point(aes(x = disp, y = mpg)) 
>
> #create two grobs
> rect <- rectGrob(gp = gpar(alpha = 0.5, col = "white"))
> circle <- circleGrob(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, r = 0.2, gp = gpar(fill = "darkred"))
>
>
> #create the viewport
> vipo <- viewport(x = 0.8, y = 0.8, 
>                 just = c("centre", "centre"),
>                 width = 0.3, height = 0.3)
> ```

I was trying `gTree()` where I can pass grobs and viewports but the output is wrong:

> ```
> plot_gtree <- gTree(children = gList(ggplotGrob(plot), rect, circle), vp = vipo)
> grid.draw(plot_gtree)
> ```

[image]

Of course it doesn't know which grob belongs in which viewport.

If I draw it like that it works fine:

> ```
> grid.draw(ggplotGrob(plot))
>
> pushViewport(vipo)
>
> grid.draw(rect)
> grid.draw(circle)
>
> popViewport()
> ```

How can I save this as I can save a ggplot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

Add it to the plot with `annotation_custom`:

```
plot = plot + annotation_custom(grobTree(rect, circle), 
                                xmin=300, xmax=400, ymin=25, ymax=30)
```

but then you need to specify the `x` & `y` coordinates.

Or add it to the plot `gtable`:

```
g = gtable::gtable_add_grob(x=ggplotGrob(plot),
                            grobs=grobTree(rect, circle, vp=vipo), 
                            t=7, l=5)

grid.newpage(); grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks a lot. Would you mind adding the argument names inside `gtable_add_grob()`?